# Why does WebGL's EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic force linear interpolation when magnifying

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, opengl-es-2.0, webgl2, mipmaps

I'm beyond confused right now, I am messing with porting minecraft java to WebGL and when I set the texture parameter `TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY` to any value above 1.0 on the terrain texture it immediately switches to using a linear magnification filter, even though I explicitly set `TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` to `NEAREST` in the next line as I bind the texture. Figure 1 shows the sampling when `TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY` is set to 1.0 and Figure 2 shows the sampling when `TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY` is set to any value above 1.0

[image: opengl nearest magnification filter]

[image: opengl linear magnification filter]

of course I can waste my time making a glsl hack to round the UV to emulate NEAREST filtering when the texture is magnified but that's a cheap hack that will definitely harm preformance and my severe OCD

so can somebody explain to me why webgl behaves this way? accurate anisotropic filtering is a must for this project

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, terrainTexture);
gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ext.TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, 16.0);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

no, there is not a single line in the program calling `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, xxxxxx);` while the terrain is rendered after the initial `NEAREST` call, it wasn't possible to begin with and I still checked many times before making this post

Comment: I am on google chrome 84 using a webgl2 context

Comment: Try using this to find the maximum value allowed in your hardware. It should not be less than 8 even on old hardware, but it is better to check this. `var max_anisotropy = gl.getParameter(ext.MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT);`

Comment: I think this might be [a bug in ANGLE](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/detail?id=4994).

Comment: @codetiger all values above 1.0 cause this problem, I already addressed this possibility

Comment: @gman thanks for posting a bug report to chromium, I appreciate